# Colour newly added bar in bar chart automatically when new data is received

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Following code basically put a colour in my bar graph based on cell D112 value. Now is there a way to automatically put colour as new data is available and new bar is added to my bar chart? For example, Cell D112 is the value for the month of Jan, now when i get value in cell D113 for the month of Feb, how do i colour the bar of that month automatically? I'm guessing there has to be some kind of a loop here right?

```
Sub ColorGraphs()

Dim ChrtObj As ChartObject
Dim Ser As Series
Dim SerPoint As Point


Set ChrtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18")


Set Ser = ChrtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)


Set SerPoint = Ser.Points(3)


With SerPoint.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

Select Case Range("D112").Value
    Case Is < 0.96
        SerPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(204, 0, 51)
        Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 0, 51)

    Case 0.96 To 0.98
        SerPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 102, 0)
        Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)

    Case Else ' larger than 0.98
        SerPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 153, 102)
        Range("P8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 102)

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. You only want to conditionally colour the last bar in the series, regardless of how many points are in the series?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)`.

This `Sub` runs te code every time a cell is changed.